# SolrCloud setup with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, search-server

I've been looking around for setup guides of solrCloud with tomcat. All the available documentation for solrCloud explains how to set it up with Jetty. I'm not sure moving to jetty from tomcat would be a great idea for production. We already have a 1 TB solr indexed data with very frequent update commits.

It would be very helpful if someone could point me to a setup guide for solrCloud with tomcat. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out/ are you still interested?  I'm currently working my way through a similar setup (less data), and would be interested to hear what you did.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/apache-solr-get-started-get

it says you can pretty much select upon installation which to use (Jetty or Tomcat):

*Next you'll have to decide which web server you choose for Solr. In the official tutorial, Jetty is used, but you can also use Tomcat. When you choose Tomcat be sure you are setting the UTF-8 encoding in the server.xml.*